# excanvas.js ie8 attachEvent

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, excanvas

I use an HTML5 canvas for drawing some graphics on an image. This is only supported in the latest browsers and in IE8 it isn't.
To get HTML5 canvas to work in IE8 I'm using excanvas. I've provided the excanvas.js script on the page, but now I get following error:

'the property or method attachEvent is not supported by this object' on this line of code:

```
el.attachEvent('onpropertychange', onPropertyChange);
```

This line is in the excanvas.js file.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Was this issue ever resolved? If so, please consider posting the answer below. Otherwise, can the issue be seen in an online resource today? Also, when testing this, were you using Internet Explorer 8, or the IE 8 Document Mode in a newer version of IE?